# Mysqldump does not work in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have run mysqldump on a test database using the bash command line and it works fine:

```
C:\\wamp\\bin\\mysql\\mysql5.6.12\\bin\\mysqldump --opt -u root -p membersite > c:\\wamp\\www\\php-backup\\membersitebackupfile1.sql
```

When I put the same line in a PHP file located in "c:\wamp\www\php-backup\dump.php" it produces a file with 0 bytes.

```
<?php

$command = "C:\\wamp\\bin\\mysql\\mysql5.6.12\\bin\\mysqldump --opt -u root -p membersite > c:\\wamp\\www\\php-backup\\membersitebackupfile1.sql";

exec($command);

?>
```

Comment: do you get any sort of error messages on any log file? (access, php, etc)

Comment: Try to get output of command using the second argument

Comment: `-p` alone requires you to enter a password interactively. Either specify a password with it `-p<password>`, or better ditch this option and create `my.cnf` file. Also shouldn't it be `mysqldump.exe`?

Comment: I just tried the second argument with no results. The browser just hangs with no output showing.
    <?php

    $command = "C:\\wamp\\bin\\mysql\\mysql5.6.12\\bin\\mysqldump --opt -u root -p membersite > c:\\wamp\\www\\php-backup\\membersitebackupfile1.sql";

    $output = array();

    exec($command, $output);

    print_r($output);

    ?>

Comment: The password is blank since there is no password for this database. It's just a test database on my local machine. I tried the mysqldump.exe and it doesn't work either.

Comment: I isolated the problem to the Apache installation on my local machine. The same PHP script works perfectly on my Siteground web hosting, so there is no problem with the script.

Comment: There is no password? Then remove this `-p` option!

Comment: Yes, removing the -p in the command worked. I now get the expected output. Thank you very much RandomSeed!

Answer (score -2):

If you are using wamp then try:

```
$cmd  = 'c: & cd "C:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.6.17/bin" & mysqldump.exe --user=root --password=root --host=localhost databasename> "C:\Directory\SQL.sql"';
```

exec($cmd);